# Issue in installing a go package

Tags: go

So,I recently started following a video tutorial and i am fairly new to golang and tried installing the forked version of bolt db using
$ go get go.etcd.io/bbolt/...
Note : I want to use this specific version
but i am getting an error which says

```
go: go.mod file not found in current directory or any parent directory.
        'go get' is no longer supported outside a module.
        To build and install a command, use 'go install' with a version,
        like 'go install example.com/cmd@latest'
        For more information, see https://golang.org/doc/go-get-install-deprecation
        or run 'go help get' or 'go help install'
```

I read a few GitHub issues which say that go get is deprecated so how do I resolve this ?
I also tried few other things such as
go install go.etcd.io/bbolt/...

Comment: go install go.etcd.io/bbolt...@latest
Nopes this didn't help.

Comment: As per the [1.18 release notes](https://go.dev/doc/go1.18) "go get now reports an error when used outside a module, since there is no go.mod file to update". If you are new to go then you should use modules; see [Get started with Go](https://go.dev/doc/tutorial/getting-started) for the right way to start (e.g. `go mod init X`; [more details here](https://go.dev/doc/tutorial/create-module)).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go modules are today's standard. Especially if you are new to Go; do not spend time on material that do not use (and teach) them.

Run `go mod init yourproject`
in your project repository root directory. This will create `go.mod` file.

Once you have that you can either:

- `import go.etcd.io/bbolt` in source code and then run `go mod tidy`. Go tool will find and add module to your dependencies (`go.mod` file). This is described in [Getting started](https://go.dev/doc/tutorial/getting-started) tutorial.
- run `go get go.etcd.io/bbolt` directly, that will update dependencies too.

[Using Go Modules](https://go.dev/blog/using-go-modules) series explains workflow in detail and will be helpful when converting commands from an outdated material.